# Retrieving the month from a growing range (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an excel sheet that is continuously receiving data which comes with a date stamp. I am making a dashboard that allows the user to select a month to review the data. My dates are formatted as MM-DD-YYYY. I have this half of the formula: `=FILTER(INDIRECT(RIGHT('Monthly Dashboard'!A3,4)&"!A5:IX")` which looks at my dashboard, reads the name of the sheet (which is titled the last 4 characters of what the dashboard user sees), and gets the range of the data. In order for it to read my month I attempted the  following: `LEFT(Indirect(RIGHT('Monthly Dashboard'!A3,4)&"!A5:A"),2=(LEFT('Monthly Dashboard'!A5,2)))`. The second part `(LEFT('Monthly Dashboard'!A5,2))` works fine where it returns to me 10 if October is selected. However that first part `LEFT(Indirect(RIGHT('Monthly Dashboard'!A3,4)&"!A5:A"),2` is not returning anything. I've added a picture of what I want in-case what I said was too confusing, and a picture of what the dashboard user sees. Thank you in advance! [image] [image]

Comment: Ramy, please share a sample copy of your sheet, to make it easier for us to work on this.  See guide here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383

Comment: Here is an example of my sheet, I can not share with you my actual sheet so if you can make it work here I can translate it over to my document. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qIYbKqRAd9qIAd14H2mMA8v6kBypcc2S4GMlh9Mm_i4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula, where you want the results:

```
=filter(C3:F8,month(C3:C8)=value(left($A$2,2)))
```

This filters the data by getting the month (a number from 1 to 12) from the date column, C, and comparing it to the VALUE of the two left characters from your dropdown list.

You can add some error checking if no data for that month.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(C3:F8, "where month(C)+1 ="&REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\d+"))
```

[image]